# Signup form not working (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a form which I need to validate and then update my database. I think I have missed something. There is a form which is there in home.php (in the public directory), there is a file called signup.php (../signup.php), there is a "Sign me up" button. The problem is that the signup() function is not being called upon clicking on it. I am providing all the relevant code. Would be glad if someone helps me out :)

Thanks

Here is the form

```
<div class="body">
<form name = "signupform" class="sky-form" onsubmit="return false;">
<header>Sign-up as an instructor <br/>
    <span style="font-size:14px;">Already Registered ?<a class="loginButton"      style="text-decoration:none; color:#0CF; cursor:pointer;">Login</a> </span>
</header>               
    <fieldset>                  
        <section>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your First Name</b>
            </label>

            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your Last Name</b>
            </label>


            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="10" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your username</b>
            </label>
            <span id = "unamestatus"></span>

            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass1" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your password</b>
            </label>

            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pass2" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Confirm your password</b>
            </label>

            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" onblur="checkemail()" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="100" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your email address</b>
            </label>

            <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" required>
                <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Where can we contact you?</b>
            </label>

        </section>
   </fieldset>     
   <footer>
    <button id = "signup_button" name = "signup_button" class="button" onclick="signup()"    >Create my account</button>
    <button type="button" class="button button-secondary back1" Back</button>

    <span id = "status"></span>
</footer>
</form>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Here is the signup.php file

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("location: message.php?msg=You are already logged in");
exit();
}
?>

<?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
include_once("connect.inc.php");
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM instructors WHERE user_name ='$username' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
//if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
//   echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
//    exit();
//}
if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
    exit();
}
if ($uname_check < 1) {
    echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
    exit();
} else {
    echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
    exit();
}
}
?>


<?php
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("connect.inc.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
$p = $_POST['p'];
//$g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
//$c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
// GET USER IP ADDRESS
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// -------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == ""){
    echo "The form submission is missing values.";
    exit();
} else if ($u_check > 0){ 
    echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
    exit();
} else if ($e_check > 0){ 
    echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
    exit();
} else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
    echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
    exit(); 
} else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
    echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
    exit();
} else {
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    // Begin Insertion of data into the database
    // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
    $cryptpass = crypt($p);
    include_once ("randStrGen.php");
    $p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
    // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO instructors (username, email, password, ip, signup, lastlogin, notifications_checked)       
            VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
    $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
    $uid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
    // Establish their row in the useroptions table
    //$sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
    //$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
    if (!file_exists("../instructors/$u")) {
        mkdir("instructors/$u", 0755);
    }
    // Email the user their activation link
    $to = "$e";                          
    $from = "auto_responder@skiandridelessons.com";
    $subject = 'skiandridelessons Account Activation';
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>skiandridelessons Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.skiandridelessons.com"><img src="http://www.skiandridelessons.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="skiandridelessons" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>skiandridelessons Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.skiandridelessons.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "signup_success";
    exit();
}
exit();
}
?>
```

Do tell me if anything is missing :)

Comment: you have not close your back button '>' and where is your signup() function ?

Comment: there is no form action and can't understand what do you mean by  <button id = "signup_button" name = "signup_button" class="button" onclick="signup()"    >Create my account</button>

Comment: @user1844933 when I started with the form, signup.php was on the same page as this form. So I guess I didn't require an action. I don't know if I am wrong

Comment: @SatishSharma The layout works perfectly. I might have missed it here but on the server, it is there.

Comment: If signup process from separate php file then you should use form action, there is two answers posted check it

Comment: Nope, tried everything you said. Still nothing. Upon clicking, nothing happens at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice this code comes from Adam Khoury's PHP social networking tutorials. You have tampered with the code in a poor manner.

Problem #1:

Your submit button is trying to call Ajax but it does not exist on the form page. (from the code you submitted)

Problem #2:

If somehow magically Ajax processed this request it would not be able to return any information since it isn't on the same page. Nor are the MySQL queries and variables.

Problem #3:

Again, if Ajax processed the information the form fields are named incorrectly. PHP is looking for $_POST['u'] and and username field is $_POST['username'].

Problem #4:

If Ajax is on the same page as the form then you still have many problems. For example, I know Adam calls the ID of the field, not the name so Ajax won't process anything.

Problem #5:

From what I can see you are using spaces in the names, IDs and other values etc. **never use spaces**

**The list goes on!**

So at this point you're probably thinking: "what can I do to fix this?"

**Don't use Ajax! It doesn't add any security.**

Here is the code I will very kindly recommend for you to use. This **should** work.

This if the form **it may need work if you require a specific look, I'm not doing it for you**:

```
<div class="body">
<form name="signupform" class="sky-form" method="POST" action="signup.php" >
<header>Sign-up as an instructor <br/>
<span style="font-size:14px;">Already Registered ?<a class="loginButton"      style="text-decoration:none; color:#0CF; cursor:pointer;">Login</a> </span>
</header>               
<fieldset>                  
    <section>

    <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstname" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your First Name</b>
        </label>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastname" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your Last Name</b>
        </label>


        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" maxlength="10" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your username</b>
        </label>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass1" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your password</b>
        </label>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pass2" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Confirm your password</b>
        </label>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="email" name="email" maxlength="100" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Enter your email address</b>
        </label>

        <label class="input" style="padding:20px;">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Address" name="address" required>
            <b class="tooltip tooltip-top-right">Where can we contact you?</b>
        </label>

    </section>
    </fieldset>     
    <footer>
<button id ="signup_button" name ="signup_button" class="button">Create my account</button>
<button type="button" class="button button-secondary back1" Back</button>
</footer>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

For the PHP code you will need this:

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
header("location: message.php?msg=You are already logged in");
exit();
}
?>

<?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
include_once("connect.inc.php");
$username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
$sql = "SELECT id FROM instructors WHERE user_name='$username'";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
$uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
  echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
  exit();
}
if ($uname_check < 1) {
  //header the user somewhere...
  exit();
} else {
  //header the user somewhere
  exit();
}
}
?>


<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"])){
// CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
include_once("connect.inc.php");
// GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
$u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['username']);
$e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['email']);
$p = $_POST['pass1'];
$ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
// DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
$sql = "SELECT id FROM instructors WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// -------------------------------------------
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
$e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
// FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == ""){
  echo "The form submission is missing values.";
  exit();
} else if ($u_check > 0){ 
  echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
  exit();
} else if ($e_check > 0){ 
  echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
  exit();
} else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
  echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
  exit(); 
} else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
  echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
  exit();
} else {
// END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
// Begin Insertion of data into the database
// Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
$cryptpass = crypt($p); **crypt is okay. I recommend Phpass**
include_once ("randStrGen.php");
$p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
// Add user info into the database table for the main site table
$sql = "INSERT INTO instructors (username, email, password, ip, signup, lastlogin, notifications_checked)       
        VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql); 
$uid = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
// Establish their row in the useroptions table
//$sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
//$query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
// Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
if (!file_exists("../instructors/$u")) {
    mkdir("instructors/$u", 0755);
}
// Email the user their activation link
$to = "$e";                          
$from = "auto_responder@skiandridelessons.com";
$subject = 'skiandridelessons Account Activation';
$message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>skiandridelessons Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.skiandridelessons.com"><img src="http://www.skiandridelessons.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="skiandridelessons" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>skiandridelessons Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.skiandridelessons.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
$headers = "From: $from\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
echo "signup_success";
exit();
}
exit();
}
?>
```

This may not be perfect for use yet but as I said I am not doing all of this code for you. If you want me to build the code for you then it will cost. And as I commented, the crypt function is fine for use, but I recommend Phpass. It's extremely solid for security and is not difficult to use.

There are many problems still... Resort to basic tutorials on W3 Schools on PHP form submission etc.

Answer (score 0):

Update your form tag like this..

```
<form name = "signupform" class="sky-form"  action="signup.php">
```

Comment: This is in case signup.php is in the same directory, right ? I tried it too but it just won't respond. I also shifted signup.php to a higher directory and put the action as action = "../signup.php", still no success.

Answer (score 0):

Add action="singup.php" method="POST"

```
<form name = "signupform" class="sky-form" onsubmit="return false;" method="POST" action="signup.php">
```

Comment: Tried that too. When I click on the "Sign me up" button, nothing happens.

Comment: add singup.php in same directory and then try

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name = "signupform" class="sky-form"  action="signup.php">

<!--input elements-->

<input type ="submit" id = "signup_button" name ="signup_button" class="button" value="Create my account"/>

</form>
```